# using normals and roughness maps on an alpha masked leaf

Tags: uv, node-editor, transparency

So i have a png of a leaf along with its normal and roughness maps that i got off of poliigon. ive got the leaf texture to work with the transparency, issue is how do i use the normal and roughness maps along side the alpha masked texture of the leaf since the 'surface' input node is already being used.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the mix shader?

Comment: Hi Spiffy, its somehow hard to explain according to mess in the Node Editor ;) ... could U please upload the .blend here? (btw what resolution is your Blender running?)

Comment: ive tried the mix shader but i dont know how to properly use it. im not very good with the node tree. im using an ultra wide monitor 21:9 at 3340x1440

Comment: Use this to upload Yo scene buddy... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5345" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5345/) . never used this before so i hope ive done this right.